# How to use cumfold or cumreduce to create stateful column

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I'm trying to create a column, that changes its value for every 1/True in target column, and keeps previous value for 0/False. So for example how to get from this

```
a = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]})
print(a)
┌─────┐
│ a   │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   │
└─────┘
```

this dataframe

```
┌─────┬────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b          │
│ --- ┆ ---        │
│ i64 ┆ str        │
╞═════╪════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ new_value1 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ new_value1 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ new_value1 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ new_value1 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ new_value2 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ new_value2 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ new_value2 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ new_value3 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ new_value4 │
└─────┴────────────┘
```

PS: adding some text so post is not mostly code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In polars, `fold`, `reduce`, `cumfold` and `cumreduce` are horizontal expressions. Meaning that they operate op columns, not on elements.

To achieve what you want, you can use `cumsum` to get a monotonically increasing integer on every `True` value.

Then we combine that result with the `format` expression to get the string output you want.

```py
a.with_column(
    pl.format("new_value_{}", pl.col("a").cumsum())
)
```

```
shape: (8, 2)
┌─────┬─────────────┐
│ a   ┆ literal     │
│ --- ┆ ---         │
│ i64 ┆ str         │
╞═════╪═════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ new_value_1 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ new_value_1 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ new_value_1 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ new_value_1 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ new_value_2 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ new_value_2 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ new_value_2 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ new_value_3 │
└─────┴─────────────┘
```